# AngularJs project not working as a single page web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate AngularJs to a existing web project(jquery). This is a part of my code :

```
<div class="medya" ng-repeat="d in data" masonry-item-dir>
  <a href="{{d.Url}}" class="onizleme"><img src="{{d.Image}}" alt="Içerigin Basligi" data-src="{{d.Image}}" srcset="{{d.Image}} 1x, {{d.Image}} 2x"></a>
  <div class="govde">
    <a href="{{d.Url}}" class="baslik">{{d.Title}}</a>
    <div class="bilgi"><a href="{{d.Url}}" class="lnk">{{d.EditorName}}</a> <span data-title="{{d.DateCreated}}" class="tooltip">{{d.CreateDate}}</span></div>
    <div class="aciklama">{{d.Content}}</div>
    <div class="alt">
      <span class="damga" title="{{d.ReadCount}} Görüntüleme"><span class="icon-eye"></span>{{d.ReadCount}}b</span>
      <a class="imle tooltip aktif" href="{{d.Url}}"><span class="icon-bookmark"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is not working as a single page application, it sends a new request and opens a new page everytime a link is clicked. I guess it's because of the `a href="{{d.Url}}"` parts I'm using. How can I change it in order to make it a single page site?

Comment: You should first read some tutorials.. You will ned ``ng-view` with `ng-route`

Comment: you just place an expression({{ }}) and it's not make it an angular app learn more about ($stateProvider, ng-sref and other angular attribute and inbuilt services).

Comment: how you're routing? are you using [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)? If yes, use `ui-sref` instead of href.

Comment: I added  `<script> var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);</script>` and  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>` to the head of my index page just now. Is it enough to be using it? I changed `href` 's to `ui-sref` and now links are not behave like links.

Answer (score 0):

A single page application needs to be able to change pages "internally". This is usually handled by a `router` module.

There are three main choices for AngularJS:

1. [UiRouter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) - I would highly recommend this as it is the most feature rich and well supported by the community.
2. [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) - This is the default Angular 1.x router. This router lacks many features of other routers.
3. [Component-Router](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router) - This is a back port of the Angular2 Component Router. The API may not be the most stable.